# how can i send multiple objects through java server socket to php socket?

Tags: java, php, json, sockets

I am trying to send multiple objects through a php socket from a java server.
Although when i try to send 2 or more json objects to php client, the website just refuses to load. But when i send only one json object, it seems to work fine.

This is the code from my java server:

```
package org.articron.server;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * @author Articron | Arno
 *         on 8-8-2015.
 */
public class TCPConnection implements Runnable {

    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private JSONObject tosend;
    private JSONObject tosend2;

    public TCPConnection(Socket client, PrintWriter writer, BufferedReader reader) {
        this.client = client;
        this.writer = writer;
        this.reader = reader;
        tosend = new JSONObject();
        tosend2 = new JSONObject();
        tosend.put("scriptid","2");
        tosend.put("name","mathias@cochet.lol");

        tosend2.put("scriptid","1");
        tosend2.put("botname","arno.gerver@gmail.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            tosend.writeJSONString(writer);
            tosend2.writeJSONString(writer);
            writer.write("END");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what the php looks like:

```
function dataTrans()
{
    $recieved = array();
    /* Get the port for the WWW service. */
    $service_port = 5678;

    /* Get the IP address for the target host. */
    $address = gethostbyname('104.251.212.75');

    /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
    if ($socket === false) {
        echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
    } else {
       // echo "OK.\n";
    }


    $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
    } else {
       // echo "OK.\n";
    }
        do{
        $obj = socket_read($socket, 1024);
            if($obj == 'END'){
                break;
            }
        array_push($recieved, json_decode($obj));
            }while(true);
    socket_close($socket);
    return $recieved;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but out of instinct I would suggest to send a JSONArray with the 2 (or more) JSONObjects inside, and in the PHP side of stuff, assume that you recieve an array, instead of many objects.